# Testcafe: How to maximize the window?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a test that opens a new window when the button is clicked but the window is not maximized. I switched to the current window and use the await t.maximizeWindow() but the target window still not maximized.

Comment: it should be await t.maximizeWindow()

Comment: Thanks for the answer Janaaaa. Yeah, right but I did use that, just a typo error on my question (sorry about that). I just want the new open window to be maximized. I have no problem on the parent window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, support for multiple browser windows is a beta feature and has several limitations. So, you cannot resize child windows or take screenshots or videos of them.
You can find more information in the TestCafe documentation: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/multiple-browser-windows.html

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you for sharing the link aleks-pro

Comment: It's been like 4 years now, any update on this ?

Comment: The TestCafe team fully supported multiple browser windows in testcafe [v1.11.0](https://testcafe.io/402964/release-notes/framework/2021-2-15-testcafe-v1-11-0-released#multiple-browser-windows-is-live-912httpsgithubcomdevexpresstestcafeissues912). You can find more info on this mode's capabilities and limitations [here](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402841/guides/intermediate-guides/multiple-browser-windows).